# Which sounds better?

Tags: word-choice

Which sentence sounds better?

-I have thoughts that there would be mutual benefits for both of us if we could
  explore new business opportunities together in IoT, Connected Cars, etc.

-I believe that there would be mutual benefits for both of us if we could 
   explore new business opportunities together in IoT, Connected Cars, etc.

I think the first one sounds a bit unnatural and the second one is better, but some of my co-workers think the opposite. Does 'have thoughts' in the first sentence sound okay to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To have thoughts* often implies that the thoughts come unbidden and unwelcome to mind, i.e., that they are [*intrusive thoughts*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusive_thought).  This is different from *thinking*, which implies a voluntary and controlled mental process.  Gently convince your co-workers that "I believe" (or even "I think") is the better choice.

While you're at it, you may drop "for both of us."  The word *mutual* implies the reciprocal nature of things, here between the first person (the speaker) and the second person (the spoken to).

Comment: Ah, yes.  A driveby downvoter, a curse on this site, strikes again.  Is this is vote for "have thoughts" meaning the same as "think"?  Or does it mean that *mutual* does not mean what I say it means?  Nobody can tell.

Comment: thank you for your comment! It was definitely helpful  :)

Comment: @joinjoli Oh, if only I was young enough to do emoticons!  It's considered impolite around to here to ask whether someone was a driveby downvoter, so I won't do that.  But the question was yours and you haven't accepted my answer.  Which you are under no obligation to do, especially if you didn't find the answer unhelpful. Do you think the answer is lacking?  Do you have evidence that contradicts my explanation?  Or is the explanation misleading or unclear?  If I knew the answers to those questions, perhaps I could improve the answer.

Comment: No, no, there must be some misunderstanding here. I found your answer helpful and thanked you. I just don't know how to "accept" your answer. Is there a button for that? I don't see any "accept" button.

Comment: @joinjoli Ah, now I understand.  Comments and answers are different.  An answer is the text to the right of the up and down triangles.  (There should be a vote number between the triangles.)  Comments appear below the answers.  You should see a checkmark below the down triangle.  Roll your mouse over the checkmark and it will give an explanation starting "Click to accept."